# Getting a dataset of Photos and hashtags of Instagram

Tags: dataset, nlp, instagram-api, hashtag

I am trying to come up with a dataset of public photos and some random hashtags regarding them from Instagram. Is there any API for that?
Also is there a dataset for a list of hashtags or object vocabulary?

Best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! you need to look for [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) this provides data based on your search queries and much more. At first you may have sign up and follow few of the tutorials to understand what extensible features they provide. Following is a good read [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-instagram-api-media-endpoints--cms-23611)

Apart from that if you are not interested in API and just want a dataset have a look at this [Social Media Repository](http://www.emilio.ferrara.name/datasets/)

Cheers!

Comment: But is it legal to store images taken from instagram? Look [here](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) `

Comment: @user2614596 Nice question! it only depends on how the data is being used. Because the API provides you with public data (it'd be strange if they are giving away private data ). From the legal perspective if you are not violating any copyright laws you should be good to go, Plus that applies on the content itself.